# javafx 2.0 how to add scroll bar in Accordion

Tags: javafx-2

the accordion height will increase once the titled pane expanded.
but since the window is a fixed height window, if the height of accordion is bigger than the window height,the content of bottom titled pane will be clipped off.

so how can i show a vertical scroll bar to display those titled panes

is there any way to add a scroll bar in accordion 
or i need to put accordion in a control which may show scroll bar when accordion exceed the height the outer control ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add a scroll pane inside the accordion and set the scroll pane size to the size of the accordion minus the heights of the bars. Your scroll pane's contents can then exceed the size of the accordion.

```
 @Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    Accordion accord=new Accordion();
    ScrollPane scroll=new ScrollPane();
    scroll.setPrefHeight(accord.getHeight());
    scroll.prefWidth(accord.getWidth());

    TitledPane title=new TitledPane();
    title.setText("Accordian");
    title.setContent(scroll);
    accord.getPanes().add(title);
    root.getChildren().add(accord);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Scroll Pane");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some basic example, please?

Comment: Sorry for the delay I wasn't using this stackoverflow account for long time. Hope it still helps someone

Comment: This does not answer the question. You've added a scrollpane to the individual `TitledPane`, not the `Accordion`. The question is how to scroll the entire `Accordion`.